# Why $P\{\frac{|W(1/n^4)|}{1/n^4}>n\}=P\{\frac{|V(1/n^4)|}{1/n^4}>n\}$ for a Wiener process $W$.

Tags: probability, statistics, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus

I stuck on an explanation to a problem in the book "Basic Stochastic Processes" by Z. Brzeniak and T. Zastawniak. Consider a Wiener process $W(t)$ and a sequence of Wiener processes $(V_n(t))$ where $V_n(t)=\frac{1}{n^2}W(n^4t)$ for each natural $n$. The explanation casually states the following equality for any $n$
$$
P\left\{\frac{|W(1/n^4)|}{1/n^4}>n\right\} =P\left\{\frac{|V_n(1/n^4)|}{1/n^4}>n\right\}
$$
without any justification. I simply can't see how this equality follows trivially from the given info. I could see how we could maybe make a $\geq$ inequality, which would actually suffice for the proof. So why does this equality hold?

Disclaimer: I'm attempting a course on stochastic calculus with not a single statistics course behind my name (I did physics instead in my junior years) , and so I am not well versed at all in statistics and probability. There's a high probability (haha) that I may be missing some standard property of probability, but even so I'd appreciate knowing what it is.

Comment: This is from the solution to Exercise 6.30 if anyone is wondering.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For each $n$ and for each $t$, $V_n(t)$ has the same distribution as $W(t)$: a normal distribution with mean zero and a variance equal to $\sqrt t$.

Comment: If I did statistics that would have jumped out at me, although I'm still kicking myself for missing it. Looking back now is it correct to say that ALL Wiener processes have the same distribution?

Comment: All standard Brownian motion, yes.